# jquery plugin problem

Tags: jquery-plugins

i created jquery plugin 
and error I get is reference error: mySlider is not defined

```
(function($){

$.fn.mySlider = function(){
    var timeOut = 4000;
    var element = this; 
    var fxDuration = timeOut/6;

    var items = $("#" + element[0].id + " li");
    var captions = $("#" + element[0].id + " li div");

    var fadeIn = function(no){
        $(items[no]).fadeIn(fxDuration, function(){
            $(captions[no]).fadeIn(fxDuration, function(){
                setTimeout(function(){fadeOut(no)}, timeOut);
            });
        });

    }

    var fadeOut = function(no){
        $(captions[no]).fadeOut(fxDuration, function(){
            $(items[no]).fadeOut(fxDuration, function(){
                fadeIn(calcNext(no));
            });
        });

    }

    var calcNext = function(no){
        return ((no+1) == items.length)? 0: (no+1);
    }

    fadeIn(0);

}
```

})(jQuery);

and called

```
   <script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <script src="mySlider.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <script>
  // alert('hi');
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert(mySlider());
            //$("#slider").mySlider();
        });
   </script>
```

It says mySlider is not defined

please help me to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not defined, since you did not define it.

You defined only `$.fn.mySlider`

You may want something like this, to have a separate function:

```
var mySlider = function() {
    $("#slider").mySlider();
};
```

Comment: i did try exactly that, see my commented out line, it didn't work so i tried to alert, and still same problem

Comment: Fisrt: you cannot alert a function that is not defined. `mySlider()` is not defined `$.fn.mySlider()` is. Second: take a look here is your code, and it does something, not sure what was your goal, but it definitly works: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/hwyJ3/